# Stream builder don't receive data (Inifinite ConnectionState = waiting) Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method which gets items from firestore and storage. I've made some changes to be able to refresh the list with a stream builder:

```dart
class ItemLab {
  final String tipo;
  final Reference elemento;
  final String pastaVideo;
  final Map video;
  final String imageUrl;

  ItemLab({
    this.tipo,
    this.elemento,
    this.video,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.pastaVideo
  });
}

class LabController {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  bool hasMore = false;
Stream<List<ItemLab>> stream;
  StreamController<List<ItemLab>> _streamController;

  LabController() {
    _streamController = StreamController<List<ItemLab>>.broadcast();
    stream = _streamController.stream..toList();
  }

  void closeStream() {
    _streamController.stream.drain();
  }

  loadLab(String submenu, [int limit]) async* {
    var parts = submenu.split('/');
    var pathSlashless = parts[0].trim();
    var subPathSlashless = parts.sublist(1).join('/').trim();

    var snapshot = await _storage.ref().child("/${submenu}");
    var retorno = await snapshot.listAll();
    List<ItemLab> conteudo = [];

    if(subPathSlashless.isEmpty || subPathSlashless == null){
      retorno.prefixes.forEach((element) {
        conteudo.add(
          ItemLab(
            tipo: 'PASTA',
            elemento: element,
          ),
        );
      });
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < retorno.items.length ; i++){
      var url = await retorno.items[i].getDownloadURL();
      conteudo.add(
        ItemLab(
          tipo: 'FILE',
          elemento: retorno.items[i],
          imageUrl: url,
        ),
      );

      if(limit != null){
        if(conteudo.length > limit){
          hasMore = true;
          yield conteudo;
        }else{
          hasMore = false;
          print("less than 9");
        }
      }
    }


      if(subPathSlashless.isNotEmpty){
        print(subPathSlashless);
        List items;
        await databaseReference
            .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
            .snapshots().forEach((element) {
              element.docs.forEach((f) {
                if(f.data()['videos'] != null){
                    items == null ? items = f.data()['videos'] :
                    items.addAll(f.data()['videos']);
                  };
                  print("ITEMS :::: >>> ${items}");
              });
        });


        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i ++){
          //print(items[i]);
          conteudo.add(
            ItemLab(
              tipo: 'VIDEO',
              elemento: null,
              video: items[i],
            ),
          );
        }

      }else{
        await databaseReference
            .collection("lab_${pathSlashless}_url")
            .snapshots().forEach((element) {
          element.docs.forEach((f) {
            if(f.data().isNotEmpty){
              //print(f.data());
              if(f.data().keys.contains("videos")){
                conteudo.add(
                  ItemLab(
                      tipo: 'PASTA',
                      pastaVideo: findFolderName(f.reference.path)
                  ),
                );
                _streamController.add(conteudo);
              }else{
                conteudo.add(
                  ItemLab(
                    tipo: 'VIDEO',
                    elemento: null,
                    video: f.data(),
                  ),
                );
                _streamController.add(conteudo);
              }
            }
          });
        });
      }

    pathSlashless = null;
    subPathSlashless = null;

    conteudo = checkDuplicateFolder(conteudo, submenu);
    yield conteudo;
  }
```

And I wanna show it in this list:

```dart
LabController ctrlLab = LabController();

loadBasicStructure(submenu ,callback, context, scrollController, deviceSize){
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: ctrl.stream,
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
```

But with this approach the list is never populated. It always show the CircularProgressIndicator but not the items.. so what i'm missing here?

Comment: It seems to me that maybe, your Firestore rules may not be allowing you to access the data. However, if you share your rules, we can rule that out. Edit your question with the rules as well.

Comment: No, i'm getting the data right in conteudo.add.. I'm sure of that

Comment: Yes but is the data actually arriving?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure in that .add it is getting the data

Comment: According to me, if there's a problem, it is in fact in the code in between, if it is not in the data retrieval, of course. What you can do is try and printing checkpoints. Like, after the first `if` in the `loadLab` function, print "Checkpoint 1" after the second one, print "Checkpoint 2" and so on...

Comment: I 'll do that and after update the question]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228952/discussion-between-armstrong-and-preet-shah).